# COUNTIF not working because column is a hyperlink

Tags: datetime, google-sheets, hyperlink, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

```
=countif(Sheet1!G2:G,"<"&today())
```

returns 0 when I expect it to return 13.  The G column has hyperlinks with text as dates. How do I make it work?

I also tried `=countif(datevalue(Sheet1!G2:G),"<"&today())`, it returns 1 instead of 13.

Comment: welcome, just paste the URL/link in your post or comment

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13EwcPV5V4e0bPrwCqQARQosKkTYisLA3HgWsMccW2Aw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: 7/18/29 is what date? 18.july.2029 or 29.july.2018 ?

Comment: Apologies. That was a typo while creating a duplicate sheet. 7/18/2019 is the correct format. i have updated it.

Comment: @player0 this works fine. thank you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

today's date is 7/18/2019, therefore, the right operator would be `<=`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(DATE(INDEX(SPLIT(A1:A, "/"),,3), 
                           INDEX(SPLIT(A1:A, "/"),,1), 
                           INDEX(SPLIT(A1:A, "/"),,2)), "<="&TODAY()))
```

[image: 0]